# Can't add "list:xxxxxxxxxxx" StreamRule to StreamingClient of Twitter API v2

Tags: python, tweepy, twitterapi-python, twitter-api-v2, sttwitterapi

I can't add "list:XXXXXXXXXX" to my rules (I can add other rules though and they work).
What I'm missing?

```
import tweepy

class TweetPrinter(tweepy.StreamingClient):
    def on_tweet(self, tweet):
        print(tweet)   
printer = TweetPrinter(bearer_token)
printer.add_rules(tweepy.StreamRule("list:XXXXXXXXXX")) 
printer.filter()
```

After executing this code instead of creating a StreamRule with an id, I got this (checking the list of the rules with `printer.get_rules()`:

`Response(data=None, includes={}, errors=[], meta={'sent': '2022-12-27T00:23:44.073Z', 'result_count': 0})`

I'm using [Tweepy 4.12](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/streamrule.html) and [Twitter API v2](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/build-a-query).

Comment: `list:` doesn't seem to be a keyword that's available in the twitter api v2 (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/filtered-stream/integrate/build-a-rule) Are you trying to search for the text "list:XXXXXX" or?

Comment: Hm.. Looks like you're right. It's not available for Filtered stream specifically (but available otherwise). Thanks for the hint!